# What happened to the "on Github" rails API documentation links?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, documentation

A few months ago there was a feature in the Rails API documentation that let you visit the a Rails source file on Github by clicking "on Github". Ryan Bates even [tweeted about it](https://twitter.com/#!/rbates/status/108946484019474432). This was a great feature because you could easily explore the source for the entire file instead of just for a single method.

Does anyone know what happened to this feature?

[image]

Comment: Hooray! It's not just my imagination! I thought it used to be very easy to get to rails source in the past...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the github links are back as of Rails 3.2.0!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe they removed them when they started using Ajax for the show. This happened when they switched to sdoc. Perhaps its an sdoc limitation, as everyone seemed to enjoy it.

I would recommend posting on the google group and get a discussion going requesting more information and/or getting them back.

You can find the group [here](http://groups.google.com/group/rubyonrails-talk).

Answer (score 0):

Rails documentation generated from using the standard Rdoc Rake task provided with the rails source still produces this extra link to github.

There's still a [flag for it in the rakefile](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/Rakefile#L98).

Whatever or whoever generates the documentation for the API must be omitting this flag.

Comment: They are no longer using rdoc, as per the official blog.

Comment: @andrewpthorp rdoc is a runtime dependency for sdoc, so it must be in there somewhere: https://rubygems.org/gems/sdoc

Comment: Good point, they made a big fuss about the switch, and that's when it disappeared though... Either way, I want it back :)